# How do I check if an item (Non-Consumable in-app purchase ) is already owned or not programmatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to know if I can check a non-consumable In-App purchase already own or not.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can check a `non-consumable` `In-App Purchase` already own or not by using android [BillingClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient)

You have to add following `dependency` in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
```

And use following `permission` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

You can get `in-app purchase` history for the current user by running `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` callback on your `mBillingClient`.

Here is an example of how I have implemented it in my project. hope it helps you.

```
 private BillingClient mBillingClient;
 private SkuDetailsParams.Builder params;
 private SkuDetails skuDetails;

protected void getPurchaseHistory() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished ");

                    mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,
                            new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int responseCode,
                                                                      List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
                                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
                                            && purchasesList != null) {

                                        boolean productFound = false;
                                        for (Purchase purchase : purchasesList) {
                                            
                                            // check is user purchased your product or not                                           
                                            if (purchase.getSku().equals("your in-app product id")) {
                                                //success! your user has bought your In-App product. Woohoo!
                                                productFound = true;

                                                // you can check user subscription details by using purchase token 
                                                checkSubscription(purchase.getPurchaseToken());
                                                prefs().setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken());
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (!productFound) {
                                            // user not purchase your product yet.
                                            prefs().setIsSubscribed(false);
                                            Log.d(TAG, "product not found");
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        prefs().setIsSubscribed(false);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase history response not ok");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                Log.d(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected ");
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. But I want to know about "Non-Consumable in-app purchase". Not for the Subscription product.

Comment: If the user cancel the order, the prefs().setIsSubscribed ends up being true anyway